# glmmPQL in R, se.fit not providing SE values

Tags: r, glm, predict

When using predict() on an object returned by glmmPQL (MASS package in R), I appear not to be able to return the standard errors. Here's a representative example of my workflow with some dummy data:

```
    #### simulate some representative data  
    set.seed(1986)      
    dep <- rbinom(200, 1, .5) # dependent binomial variable
    set.seed(1987)
    ind <- rnorm(200) # Gaussian independent variable
    set.seed(1988)
    ran <- rep(1:5, 40) # random factor

    ##### use PQL to run binomial GLMM     
    anTest <- glmmPQL(dep~ind, random=~1|ran, family=binomial)

    ##### specify values of *ind* at which to predict. expand.grid() is overkill here...
    newData <- expand.grid(ind=seq(min(ind), max(ind), length.out=100))

    #### and generate predictions
    pred <- predict(anTest, newdata=newData, type="response", level=0, se.fit=TRUE)
    (newData <- data.frame(newData, fit=pred))
```

However, as you can see, even though se.fit is set to TRUE, only predictions are generated by the function. What's going on here? I've tried doing this with simulated Poisson and Gaussian data and I still get no standard errors. Help please!

I'm running R Studio v 0.98.490 on Apple OSX v. 10.9.1

Comment: There is no `se.fit` parameter in `predict.glmmPQL`.

Comment: I see...The package BradleyTerry2 appears to have a predict.glmmPQL that has se.fit, but this package appears just not to work. Any other ideas as to how to achieve an estimate of confidence around predictions?

Comment: This is actually a difficult problem for mixed effects models. You need to do some research.